# Reading bmp file and sending data to array

Tags: c, fread, bmp

I'm trying to get some information about bmp files. For instance, one of the things I'm trying to get is the height of the file. To do so, I'm using the following lines of code:

```
char params[size];
fread (params, 1, size, bmpfile);
*height = *((int *)(params + 22));
```

However, whenever I print the height, I get 0. Why is what I'm doing incorrect, and what should I change? Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: I suspect it has to do with my fread, but I'm unsure what to do about it

Comment: Look at any format description. It seems you are reading "The number of color planes", not the height. (And you are making assumptions about its endianness matching your system, which may bite you back on another system, or with another format.)

Answer (score 1):

> `fread (params, 1, size, bmpfile);`

The second parameter should be element size, and the third parameter should be element count. You should write that as

```
fread (params, size, 1, bmpfile);
```

Although the result will be the same, except the return value for `fread` will be different. The rest is essentially correct. Add error check to find the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *bmpfile = fopen("c:\\test\\test.bmp", "rb");
    if(!bmpfile)
    {
        printf("file not found\n");
        return 0;
    }

    char params[54] = { 0 };
    int result = fread(params, sizeof(params), 1, bmpfile);
    if(result != 1)
    {
        printf("not bitmap file\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if(strncmp(params, "BM", 2) != 0)
    {
        printf("not bitmap file\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int width = *(int*)(params + 18);
    int height = *(int*)(params + 22);
    int bitcount = *(int*)(params + 28);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", width, height, bitcount);
    fclose(bmpfile);
    return 0;
}
```